# Can I convert Lubuntu Desktop 16.04 to Server?

Tags: server, 16.04, lubuntu

Is there a way I can convert Lubuntu Desktop 16.04 to Server? I found [Can I convert Ubuntu Desktop 14.04 to Server?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/511463/can-i-convert-ubuntu-desktop-14-04-to-server) but that's for Ubuntu 14.04, not Lubuntu 16.04, and I'm not sure if it will work (for a start, I don't have "ubuntu-desktop" installed).

Comment: in place of `ubuntu-desktop` you should try `lubuntu-desktop`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the following:

```
sudo apt autoremove lxde lubuntu-desktop
sudo apt purge lxde lubuntu-desktop
```

Then install whatever packages you need for your server to run.  (Ie: apache, samba, mail server, or whatever else you need.)

Comment: It says "Package 'lxde' is not installed, so not removed" and the same for 'lubuntu-desktop'.

Comment: Try `lubuntu-core` and `lxde-core`.