# Transform Ubuntu 16.04 to Ubuntu server

Tags: 16.04

Is it possible to transform Ubuntu 16.04 to an Ubuntu server? Without deleting and reinstalling...

Comment: So far I did this:                                                                                                             [code]sudo apt-get install ubuntu-server[/code]

Answer (score 1):

Your question is similar to [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/511463/can-i-convert-ubuntu-desktop-14-04-to-server). Please have a look at it.

And if you just need the commands to do the job, you can visit [this](http://theedgeofthecloud.blogspot.in/2015/01/convert-ubuntu-14041-desktop-to-ubuntu.html) blog, but before executing a command you should always know what you are doing.