# Install Ubuntu on Macbook6.1: where can I find amd64+mac iso

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb, mac, iso

I am trying to install Xubuntu (or any other Ubuntu distribution) on my old Macbook6.1.

I tried booting from USB sticks which I have prepared with Unetbootin on MacOS, with Rufus on windows, and from a DVD burned on MacOS.

The bootable USBs or DVD doesn't appear as bootable option when starting the Macbook6.1 and holding the `alt` key.

I don't understand yet where the problem is.

I found a clue on [this topic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28495/how-do-i-get-my-mac-to-boot-from-an-ubuntu-usb-key), where the OP was suggested to use a `amd64+mac` iso.

Where can I find such iso? I tried [here](http://releases.ubuntu.com/?_ga=2.31438911.1072020556.1541323844-1160285835.1535386024) already, with no luck.

Or else, is something else wrong in my installation method?

Comment: That special ISO was around years ago and AFAIK it was meant to solve a specific problem. For all 64-bit Macs the usual amd64 should work. If you can't boot it try to install rEFInd first in the original OS.

Comment: thank you for your comment, I managed to boot the image after installing rEFInd in the original OS.

Comment: https://mattgadient.com/linux-dvd-images-and-how-to-for-32-bit-efi-macs-late-2006-models/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `amd64+mac` ISO versions were developed for early Mac's with 64 bit processors, but only 32 bit EFI firmware. The resulting installations BIOS booted 64 bit versions of Ubuntu Linux. These installations also used the GUID Partition Tables (GPT) instead of the legacy MBR partition tables.

Your Mac has 64 bit EFI firmware. However, there is no reason you can not install a 64 bit BIOS booting Ubuntu on your Mac. Unfortunately, the last released `amd64+mac` ISO version was [Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS (Trusty Tahr)](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/14.04.5/release/). For the desktop version download file `ubuntu-14.04.5-desktop-amd64+mac.iso`. Once installation is complete, you will be prompt to upgrade to Ubuntu 16. The instructions for upgrading from Ubuntu 16 to the current version (Ubuntu 18) are given [here](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-upgrading-ubuntu-desktop?_ga=2.142138930.1871628289.1541543488-1234701023.1540106370#0).

Beware of the following:

- Not all Mac can BIOS boot. Apple starting eliminating the BIOS starting with the 2015 models. You Model does have a BIOS.
- Many Macs with a BIOS will not BIOS boot an operating systems unless the drive is hybrid partitioned. If necessary, you can use `gdisk` to change the drive partitioning to hybrid.
- To BIOS boot Ubuntu on a Mac, you should create a 1 MB `biosgrub` partition. You need to create this partition in addition to any other partitions you normally create for an Ubuntu installation.
- There is no guarantee your Mac can BIOS boot Ubuntu and be upgraded to the current version. You will have to try to find out.

> Note: An example of installing Ubuntu Server is given as the accepted answer to the question [Booting 64-bit Ubuntu Images on a First-Generation Mac Pro 1,1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1001238/booting-64-bit-ubuntu-images-on-a-first-generation-mac-pro-1-1).

Comment: If I understand correctly, since my Mac has a 64 bit EFI firmware, I don't necessarily need the `amd64+mac` ISO version which is for early Mac's with 32 bit firmware. But are you suggesting that I get this `am64+mac` version regardless?

I suppose that I could not boot because I haven't partitioned my drive yet (I was initially planning on getting rid of the original OS and installing Ubuntu only). I will use `gdisk` to change the drive partitioning to hybrid and to create a 1 MB `biosgrub` partition.

Comment: @Bielorusse: If you choose the option to erase the drive before installing, then you will get a BIOS booting Ubuntu which uses the legacy MBR partition table. The GPT will not be used and therefore there will be no need for a `biosgrub` partition.

Comment: @Bielorusse: I am not suggesting you choose the legacy BIOS booting `amd64+mac` version over the EFI booting version. You suggested this in your question. I was just providing and answer on how to get the latest `amd64+mac` version.